# Why are these two same functions different?

Tags: c

**IDE**

Visual studio 2017

**Main**

```
int cnt = 0;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cnt = func(4);
    printf("%d", cnt);
}
```

**Function A**

```
int func(int num)
{
    if (num < 2)
    {
        cnt += num;
        return cnt;
    }

    func(num / 2);

    cnt += num % 2; <<<
}
```

**Result**

> 1

**Function B**

```
int func(int num)
{
    if (num < 2)
    {
        cnt += num;
        return cnt;
    }

    func(num / 2);

    if (num % 2) cnt++; <<<
}
```

**Result**

> 0

**Question**

I think the result of two functions above should be the exact same, but it shows different results.

> Where does this difference come from?

Comment: From where the hell come the variable "cnt" ? Is that a global variable ?

Comment: Both your functions have undefined behavior, they flow out of the body without returning an int.

Comment: @Tom's Yep. cnt is global variable. I added that.

Comment: Functions definition should return void

Comment: @Mat I know that both functions are undefined behavior. I am wondering why the results of these two functions differ.

Comment: Probably because you have `cnt = func(4);` in your `main`, so the "undefined return" is overwriting the global value accumulated in `cnt`. If you just had `func(4);` it _might_ do what you want/expect (although it's a bad way of doing it).

Comment: @EthanChoi: undefined behavior means you can't reason about the code, it is meaningless. If you want to know what happens in that specific instance with that specific compiler and flags, look at the generated assembly. But from a C perspective, your code has no meaning.

Comment: Because ... undefined behavior ? That's the exact defintion of UNDEFINED behavior : You can't expect something if it's undefined.

Comment: Thank you all for answering my questions. It's just undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither function actually returns a value, so they will both have undefined behavior.

Comment: Technically, the undefined behavior occurs in using the return value, not in the function itself. C permits a function declared with a non-void return type to flow off its terminating `}` provided the caller does not use the return value.